# How to merge separate function declarations in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make an [`*-as-promised` version](https://github.com/DanielRamosAcosta/async-promises) of the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) library in TypeScript, reusing [`@types/async`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/async) types.

My problem is that [@types/async at the .filter function](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/async/index.d.ts#L123) is exporting two functions types with the same name:

```
export function filter<T, E>(arr: T[] | IterableIterator<T>, iterator: AsyncBooleanIterator<T, E>, callback?: AsyncResultArrayCallback<T, E>): void;
export function filter<T, E>(arr: Dictionary<T>, iterator: AsyncBooleanIterator<T, E>, callback?: AsyncResultArrayCallback<T, E>): void;
```

But I [only export one .filter function](https://github.com/DanielRamosAcosta/async-promises/blob/705bdd6160f3e5277dffcd238ed930c6496b4192/lib/filter.ts#L29):

```
function filter<T>(
    arr: async.Dictionary<T> | T[] | IterableIterator<T>,
    iterator: (item: T) => Promise<boolean>
  ): Promise<Array<(T | undefined)> | undefined> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    async.filter(arr, (item, cb) => {
      iterator(item)
        .then(res => cb(undefined, res))
        .catch(err => cb(err));
    }, (err, results) =>
      err
      ? reject(err)
      : resolve(results)
    );
  });
}
```

When compiling, this gives me the following error:

```
lib/filter.ts(32,18): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Dictionary<T> | IterableIterator<T> | T[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Dictionary<T>'.
  Type 'IterableIterator<T>' is not assignable to type 'Dictionary<T>'.
```

So, How can I merge those declaration in just one?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strange that the typing isn't a single function signature with the union of the three possible types for the `arr` parameter.  You might want to consider filing an issue or a pull request to the `async` typing library to fix it.

Even so, it would be nice if the compiler would allow you to call the function the way you have, since you know it is safe to do so.  But as you see, [it won't](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107), at least as of TypeScript v2.5.

The easiest workaround: since you know for a fact what the compiler doesn't know... namely, that the existing `filter` function will indeed accept an `arr` of type `T[] | IterableIterator<T> | Dictionary<T>`, it is safe to tell the compiler not to worry by asserting `arr` is of type `any` which disables type checking:

```
function filter<T>(
    arr: async.Dictionary<T> | T[] | IterableIterator<T>,
    iterator: (item: T) => Promise<boolean>
  ): Promise<Array<(T | undefined)> | undefined> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    async.filter(arr as any, (item, cb) => {
      iterator(item)
        .then(res => cb(undefined, res))
        .catch(err => cb(err));
    }, (err, results) =>
      err
      ? reject(err)
      : resolve(results)
    );
  });
}
```

There are other workarounds, such as writing a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to split the call to `async.filter()` into two calls depending on the type of `arr`; or wrap the  `async.filter` function with something similar to [`intersectFunction()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107#issuecomment-312070139) so that it accepts the union you want it to, but these workarounds are bulkier and have runtime effects, so I'd stick to the `as any` method above.

Hope that helps; Good luck!